# bitbucket удаленный репозиторий

Tags: git, bitbucket

Есть удаленный репозиторий на bitbucket.
После неудочного merge веток, на bitbucket в source files не видно новые файлы.

В локальном же все нормально - делаю push origin master - up-to-date. Старые файлы коммитятся как нужно.

В разделе commits на bitbucket новые файлы видны.
Что с этим делать и в какую сторону вообще смотреть?
Заменить удаленный репозиторий, к сожалению, не представляется возможным.

Comment: А ветка точно нужная выбрана? А если сделать clone с bitbucket будут файлы?

Comment: Ветка осталась только одна - master
Если сделать clone - все хорошо, файлы есть.
Если перейти в commits, выбрать коммит - все нормально, файлы есть.
Т.е ситуация вида:
https://bitbucket.org/username/repo/src/*/*/ - тут нету
https://bitbucket.org/username/repo/src/commit_hash/*/ - здесь есть

Comment: А Вам важно, что показывается в Source? Если да, то напишите им в техподдержку, пусть посмотрят что там не так.

Comment: Лично мне - нет, но к сожалению такая необходимость есть.
Ну, видимо придется написать, если не найдется решение.

Comment: @TorSen, нужные файлы в ветке мастер или в какой-то другой ветке? В src по-умолчанию отображается именно мастер.

Comment: Ветка после мержа только одна - master